# Add custom delimiter in key-value pair

Tags: sed, text-formatting

I have data which are in "Key:value" form (901 S 902 M 905 F 906 WAPENC 907 31 908 371 909 38765469947/TYPE=PLMN and so on ) where keys are 901,902,905,906.....so on and respective values are after spaces S,M,F,WAPENC,31...so on .

Input example

```
901 S 902 M 905 F 906 WAPENC 907 31 908 371 909 38765469947/TYPE=PLMN ..... continuous data
```

I want to convert into key:value,key:value... format.

Desired output:

```
901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC,907:31,908:371,909:38765469947/TYPE=PLMN and so on .....
```

Tried using perl and sed but not getting expected result

Comment: May any of the values contain embedded spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so?

```
% perl -pe 's/(\S+) (\S+) ?/$1:$2,/g; s/,$//' file.txt
901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC,907:31,908:371,909:38765469947/TYPE=PLMN
```

or

```
% sed -E -e 's/([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ?/\1:\2,/g; s/,$//' file.txt
901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC,907:31,908:371,909:38765469947/TYPE=PLMN
```

Both basically say to take a string of non-spaces, a space, another string of non-spaces, and an optional space; and then put back the captured strings of non-spaces with a <strike>comma and a colon</strike> colon and a comma. And then to remove the last <strike>colon</strike> comma from the end of the line. If there's an odd field at the end, it'll be left as-is. I.e. the input `foo bar doo` will turn into `foo:bar,doo`.

Or in AWK, looping over the fields:

```
% awk '{ for (i=1; i <= NF; i+=2) {printf "%s:%s", $i, $(i+1); if (i <= NF - 2) printf "," }; printf "\n" }' file.txt
901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC,907:31,908:371,909:38765469947/TYPE=PLMN
```

(This will turn `foo bar doo` into `foo:bar,doo:`, adding the stray <strike>comma</strike> colon at the end.)

Comment: @Freddy, ehh, thanks, looks like I can't read, again.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    printf $i (i==NF ? ORS : (i%2 ? ":" : ",")) 
}' file
```

Testing:

```
$ printf 'a\na b\na b c\na b c d\n' | awk '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    printf $i (i==NF ? ORS : (i%2 ? ":" : ",")) 
}'
a
a:b
a:b,c
a:b,c:d
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using tr and sed commands as follows:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < infile.txt | sed '1~2s/$/:/' | sed '2~2s/$/,/' | tr -d '\n'

901:S,902:M,905:F,906:WAPENC,907:31,908:371,909:38765469947/TYPE=PLMN,
```

Explanation

the first tr puts one item per line

the first sed adds colon to the end of every other line starting from line 1

the second sed adds a comma at the end of every other line starting from line 2

the last tr removes all end of lines to create a long data string as before

to get rid of the last comma use another sed:

```
sed 's/.$//'
```

Comment: You have a trailing `,`